# Using linq to entities to swap out database identity value for text value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a form holding user information.  One of the form elements is a dropdownlist containing a list of countries.  The formview is bound to a database table which stores a country ID, and not the country name.  I have a foreign key defined between my Users table and my Countries table..  This is also reflected in my entity data model.

Given that the framework is aware of the relationship between the 2 tables, what is the quickest way to swap out the country ID for the country name when displaying the user data on a web page?  I am currently running the following code to accomplish this:

```
protected void CstCountryLabel_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (kdEntities db = new kdEntities())
        {
            Label lbl = sender as Label;

            int cntID = int.Parse(Eval("CstCntID").ToString());

            IQueryable<Country> countries = from Countries in db.Countries
                                                  where Countries.CntID == cntID
                                                  select Countries;

            var firstOrDefault = countries.FirstOrDefault();
            lbl.Text = firstOrDefault != null ? firstOrDefault.CntDescription : "";
        }
    }
```

To me, it seems like there's probably a better way since i've defined the relationship between the 2 tables in the entity framework diagram.

Comment: No sure why you are trying to "Swap" them, why not display the name and use the ID as the key? At least that is how the dropdown lists are used, the value field and a display field working together, displaying the Name and recording the selected values's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I go completely model - centric when working with my entities.  Without knowledge of how you are defining your entity relationships I will go with CodeFirst.

## The classes

### User

```cs
[Table("tblUsers")]
class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

### Country

```cs
[Table("tblCountries")]
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Country Find(MyContext db, int id)
    {
        return db.Countries.Find(id);
    }

    public static Country Find(MyContext db, string CountryName)
    {
        var matches = from c in db.Countries where c.Name == CountryName select c;
        if (matches.Count() > 0)
        {
            return matches.First();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Context

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext () : base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

### Mess with that Data

```cs
    public void Main()
    {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();
        Country Canada = Country.Find(db, "Canada");
        var users = from u in db.Users select u;
        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            u.Country = Canada;

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In this way Entity Framework can do the work of setting the reference values, all you have to worry about is working with concrete objects.

Again, I don't know what form your entities take, but Entity Framework works mostly uniformly between its incarnations.

Displaying the drop-down list should be pretty straightforward.  I have recently been doing something similar in an MVC app with a listbox (I write about Country objects, but in my example I am doing Telephone Carriers).  I created a ViewModel class to contain my User record, and also a SelectList which contains a list of all of the Countries, the TextValue (countryName) and the DataValue (CountryID) and a function to determine if any specific element is to be selected on the list.  It looks something like this:

### ViewModel

```cs
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public UserProfileViewModel() 
    {
        AllCarriers = new AspAppServicesContext().Carriers.ToList();
        selCarrier = new SelectList(AllCarriers, "ID", "Name", null);
    }

    public UserProfileViewModel(RegisterModel profile)
    {
        this.MyProfile = profile;
        AllCarriers = new AspAppServicesContext().Carriers.ToList();
        selCarrier = new SelectList(AllCarriers, "ID", "Name", this.MyProfile.CarrierID);
    }

    public RegisterModel MyProfile { get; set; }
    public List<Carrier> AllCarriers { get; set; }
    public SelectList selCarrier { get; set; }
    public object SelectedCarrier { get; set; }
}
```

### ListBox Example

```cs
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarrierID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBox("SelectedCarrier", Model.selCarrier)
        </div>
```

In this example, the outputted page will have a listbox whose name is SelectedCarrier, and each item in the listbox will be something like:

```
<option value="1">Canada Telecom</option>
```

Value is the ID, and Canada Telecom is the Carrier name which is displayed in the listbox.  On submit, an array of string is returned to the SelectedCarrier (the name of the listbox) property on the ViewModel to be done with what you will.  In my case, I used the following on my controller to make my changes to the users profile:

```cs
if (model.SelectedCarrier != null)
{
    string[] SelectedCarrier = (string[])model.SelectedCarrier;
    profile.CarrierID = int.Parse(SelectedCarrier[0]);
}
profile.Save();
```